# Subset continuous data in one dataframe around field calibration in a second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I'm trying to subset continuous data to find the last *real* record before field calibration and the first *real* record after relaunch so that I can compare the data before and after calibration. In order to attempt to find the *real* records I'm trying to subset an hour on either side of the field calibration. I have two dataframes, one with the continuous data, and one with the field calibration data.

Continuous dataframe looks like this (pals.control.sub in code):

| DateTime2 | DO | TEMP | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-30 10:30:00 | 7.07 | 25.1 | NO FLAG |
| 2021-06-30 11:00:00 | 6.94 | 25.1 | NO FLAG |

Field Calibration dataframe looks like this (pals.control.fc in code):

| Date2 | YSI.DO | YSI.TEMP | DO.calc | DO.conc | New Gain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-09 11:58:00 | 8.05 | 24.6 |  |  | 1.029 |
| 2021-06-30 13:38:00 | 7.10 | 27.7 | 5.99 | 6.14 | 1.055 |

Here's what I've tried:

```
pals.control.fc$fc.high<-pals.control.fc$DATE2+hours(2)
pals.control.fc$fc.low<-pals.control.fc$DATE2-hours(2)
pals.control.nn.fc<-subset(pals.control.sub,(DateTime2 >= pals.control.fc$fc.high &
DateTime2<=pals.control.fc$fc.low))
```

But that wasn't giving me the full range of values between the "low" and "high" times,  it was giving me records that were close to the "low" and "high" times but nothing in between.

I got this code to work, but it's clunky and I need it to be less manual because I have a lot of these dataframes to check.

```
pals.control.nn.fc<-subset(pals.control.sub,c(DateTime2 >= '2021-06-09 10:58:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-06-09 12:58:00')|
                                             (DateTime2 >= '2021-06-30 12:38:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-06-30 14:38:00')|
                            (DateTime2 >= '2021-07-19 11:28:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-07-19 13:28:00')|
                             (DateTime2 >= '2021-08-11 12:40:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-08-11 14:40:00')|
                             (DateTime2 >= '2021-08-26 14:12:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-08-26 16:12:00')|
                             (DateTime2 >= '2021-10-06 14:38:00' & 
                                                DateTime2<='2021-10-06 16:38:00')|
                             (DateTime2>= '2021-10-29 12:20:00'&DateTime2<='2021-10-29 14:20:00'))
```

Happy to answer questions.

Comment: Actually the workaround is not subsetting the right data. Back to the drawing board.